# JavaScript change function name by adding an increment number to it's end

Tags: javascript, function, dynamic, concatenation, increment

I'm trying to change function name by adding an increment number to it's end each time it gets executed, to achieve a new function name each time the code is executed.

```
<button id="Btn">alert text</button>
```

```
function text1(){
    alert("This is text1");
}

function text2(){
    alert("This is text2");
}

function text3(){
    alert("This is text3");
}

var Btn = document.getElementById("Btn");
var i = 1;

Btn.addEventListener("click", function alertText(){

i++;

//bellow line in the first time should be text2()

text+i();

}
```

Comment: This looks like an X/Y problem - you COULD do `window["text"+i]()` but I would strongly recommend `const texts = ["Text 1","Text2","Text 3"]; alert(texts[i])`

Comment: use array of functions for such need

Comment: Use an array of functions, not a bunch of globals named numerically. Better yet, since the functions are identical except for a string literal in each: put the strings in the array and pass them to the function as an argument.

Comment: The actual problem you're trying to solve is to run different code each time the button is clicked. There are various ways to do this as you can see from the comments; creating a bunch of numbered but otherwise almost identical functions is the worst possible way.

Comment: Here's one way to solve this: https://jsfiddle.net/g9dcf2a3/

Comment: Here is another https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/f378gu92/

Comment: Thanks a lot @Chris G  and all of you guys for the help and the useful information